# Pig - Calculating percentage of total for a field

Tags: apache-pig

I am trying to calculate % of total for a value for in a field.

For example, for data (name, ct)

(john, 1000)
(Dan, 2000)
(liz, 2000)

I want the output to be (name, % of ct to the total)

(john, .2)
(Dan, .4)
(liz, .4)

```
data  = load 'fakedata.txt' as (name:chararray,sqr:chararray,ct:int);
A = foreach data generate name, ct;
A = FILTER A by ct is not null;
B = group A all;
C = foreach B generate SUM(A.ct) as tot;
D = foreach A generate name, ct/(double)C.tot;
dump D;
```

ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1000: Error during parsing. Invalid alias: C in {name: bytearray,ct: int}

I am following exactly how it is given in the http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/basic.html
an example code in section - "Casting Relations to Scalars"

If I say Dump C, then the output is correctly generated as 5000. So there is a problem in the D. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The below works for me without any error. This is basically same as what you have. Not sure why you are getting this error. Which version of pig are you using?

```
data = load 'StackData' as (name:chararray, marks:int);
grp = GROUP data all;
allcount = foreach grp generate SUM(data.marks) as total;
perc = foreach data generate name, marks/(double)allcount.total;
dump perc
```

Answer (score 0):

In Relation `D`, you are looping over Relation `A` again - it knows knowing about `C`.

I'd suggest calculating the SUM, then doing JOIN so each entry contains the sum. That way you'll be able to calculate the % total for each entry.